# Can every square matrix be written as product of an invertible matrix and a projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, projection-matrices

Let A be a square matrix.
Will there always be an invertible matrix B and a projection matrix P such that A = BP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure: $A = (A+E)\Pi$ where $\Pi$ is the (orthogonal) projection onto $(\ker A)^\perp$ and E is any matrix with $\ker E = (\ker A)^{\perp}$ and $\operatorname{Im} E = \operatorname{Im}(A)^\perp$

Comment: I am sort of new to linear algebra so I am not completely sure I understand the proof. But will there always be a matrix E and a matrix Π s.t. A=(A+E)Π for any square matrix?

Comment: @AvaSoyet  Yes. Maybe this will help: let $x$ be arbitrary, then $Ax = A I x = A ((I-\Pi) + \Pi )x = A(I-\Pi)x + A\Pi x$. Since $\Pi$ is the projection onto $(\ker A)^\perp$, $I-\Pi$ is the projection onto $\ker A$. But then $A(I-\Pi)x=0$ for all $x$, so $A(I-\Pi)$ must be the zero matrix. Hence $A=A\Pi$. Similarly, it follows $E\Pi=0$. Thus $(A+E)\Pi = A\Pi + E\Pi = A + 0 = A$

Answer (score 2):

The most direct answer: this result is implied by the *Rank Normal Form* of $A$
(which slightly overloads OP's notation)

$A= P\begin{bmatrix} I_r &\mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix} Q^{-1}= \Big(P Q^{-1}\Big) \Big( Q\begin{bmatrix} I_r &\mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix} Q^{-1}\Big)= BP' $

where $B$ is invertible  and $P'$ is idempotent